# Can LTTng analyze multithreading problems by tracing the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, debian, lttng

I am looking for a method to analyze the multithreading problems in Linux user programs without affecting the program's own behaviour. I'm wondering whether it is possible to analyze the multithreading problem of user programs from the kernel event tracer or not?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, LTTng works very well for that use-case, you can start by enabling the scheduling events (sched*), the statedump events (lttng_statedump_*) and the system calls events and you should have quickly a good idea of your program behavior. You can look at the trace in TraceCompass to inspect it visually, or with the lttng-analyses scripts to extract usage and latency metrics from your trace.

Comment: Could you tell me what system call events should I enable?

Comment: Moreover, how can I observe the mutex lock/unlock events of POSIX thread by tracing the Linux kernel?

Comment: You should  start with all system calls (lttng enable-event -k --syscall -a) and after you know what you are looking for, you could enable only the ones you really want, but it depends on your application and what you want to observe.

Comment: You won't see all the mutex lock/unlock from the kernel trace, if you want to see everything, you need to use LTTng-UST with the liblttng-ust-pthread-wrapper.so library preloaded.

Comment: Thank you, I will check that